# android load small image from sd card to fill in imageview(full height width)

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I want to load a bitmap from sdcard with fill full height width of imageview i have done this code

```
im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

im.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b = im.getDrawingCache();
            //  im.setImageBitmap(b);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "TEST1.jpg");
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                File imgFile = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "TEST1.jpg");
                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                    im.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                                        //  im.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);//this is also not giving me proper o/p




                //  im.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                            .getAbsolutePath());
                    im.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
```

but it not working

It display like this But Actually it must display in full screen

Actually what i want to do is load any bitmap resizing it and want to display only selected portion of image in same imageview but selected image portion in fill imageview

[image: This]

Comment: just give imageview scaletype to fitxy

Comment: no i need it to matrix as i am moving that image using 2 fingures

Comment: and worked with fitxy also but not working

Comment: @Pragna Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** Just saw the comment saying you want to zoom etc.

Save yourself the headache of reinventing the wheel and check-out Chris Banes' great [PhotoView library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

Comment: @Pragna Perhaps post another question with the specific issues you're having getting PhotoView working. Just respond here with the link so I can find it and I'll give you a hand (assuming someone else doesn't beat me to it).